# Specify a GDB feature class using Python Tkinter dialogue box

Tags: python, arcpy, file-geodatabase, tkinter

I tried to specify a feature class from a GDB dataset through Python Tkinter tkFileDialog.askopenfilename. Below is the script. It worked for me in the past when I was dealing with .txt or .las files. However, this time it is not giving me the GDB feature class, which has no file extension here. Please advise.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

import Tkinter,tkFileDialog
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import ttk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
from tkFileDialog import askopenfile


env.workspace = "C:\\temp\\miniPilot\\miniPilot.gdb"

def browseFor_inFC():
    inFC_name = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, initialdir=r'C:\temp\miniPilot\miniPilot.gdb\data', \
                                                   title='Choose a feature class')
    inFC.set(inFC_name)

def cancel():
    root.destroy()

def remove():
    fields = arcpy.ListFields(inFC)

    for field in fields:
        print field.name
        if field.name <> "OBJECTID" and field.name <> "SHAPE" and field.name <> "SHAPE_Length":

            arcpy.DeleteField_management(inFC, field.name)



root=Tk()
root.title("XXXXXX")

# The first frame named 'mainframe'
mainframe = Frame(root, relief='flat', borderwidth=6)
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

# set up Tkinter variables, which are global variables, for the first gui -- the root window
inFC = StringVar()

# widgets on the mainframe
Label(mainframe, text="Specify the feature class: ").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=E)
inFC_entry = Entry(mainframe, width=36, textvariable=inFC)
inFC_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))
inFC_browser_Button=Button(mainframe, text="...", height=1, width=3, command=browseFor_inFC).grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=W)

# two button widgets 
refract_Button=Button(mainframe, text="OK", command=remove).grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=E)
cancel_Button=Button(mainframe, text="CANCEL", command=cancel).grid(column=4, row=3, sticky=W)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop()   # create an event loop
```

Comment: Right. I used arcpy to specify a GDB feature class before. However, I cannot create multiple nice-looking GUIs with arcpy.:-) So, the question here is, is there a way to specify a GDB feature class through a Tkinter GUI? Thanks.

Comment: Why not use [`pythonaddins.OpenDialog`](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//014p00000021000000)?

Comment: Here's the update:

Comment: def browseFor_inFC():
    ws_name = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()
    #print ws_name
    env.workspace = ws_name
    #print env.workspace
    wsName.set(ws_name)
    feature_classes = []
    #fc = ()
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(ws_name, datatype="FeatureClass",type="Polyline"):
        for filename in filenames:
            feature_classes.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
            print filename

    print feature_classes
    #print fc
    #fcCombo['values']=fc

Answer (score 2):

Here's the update:
I used tkFileDialog.askdirectory() to get the gdb name to set the workspace. Then I used arcpy.da.Walk() from the data access module to load the feature classes into an array. My next step would be, put a ttk combobox on the GUI and load feature classes into the drop-down of the combobox so users get to specify the feature class to do whatever further manipulations. A portion of the script is listed below. Definitely, I am going to try pythonaddins.OpenDialog, too. Thanks Jason for pointing to a new direction.

```
def browseFor_inFC():
    ws_name = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()
    #print ws_name
    env.workspace = ws_name
    #print env.workspace
    wsName.set(ws_name)
    feature_classes = []
    #fc = ()
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(ws_name, datatype="FeatureClass",type="Polyline"):
        for filename in filenames:
            feature_classes.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
            print filename

    print feature_classes
    #print fc
    #fcCombo['values']=fc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a file dialogue to select a FileGDB feature class as it is not a file, it's part of a database. You need to use Esri arcpy or a library that implements the Esri FileGDB or Open FileGDB APIs such as GDAL.